# run MS Access macro on current access process without opening again

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

I have an access database that connects to multiple sql server databases using windows authentication.  Before opening this access database, I have to use the 'runas' command in command line to run the application as a different domain user, which is the same domain as sql server.  Now I need the ability to schedule reports from the access database at certain times and I know I can do this using task scheduler, which will always open the database first.  This doesn't work for me since I can't automate the 'runas' command since I'll always be prompted for a password.

Is there a way to run a script to run the access macros on my access database that is currently open (on an existing process)?  For example, if I need to send 3 reports throughout the day, could the script be called from task scheduler to run the Access macros on the current instance and not open up a new instance.

Thanks
AJ

Comment: Everything I have seen requires using "runas". In my company, we were issued a special account to use for this. The ability to log into a PC with this account is disabled, but can be used in the task scheduler and has local admin rights. You may want to talk to your Mgr about getting an account like this if you are under heavy security restrictions like our company is.